# How to create array in json-schema draft-07 where items have an `allOf` and an `oneOf`?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have tried quite a few things. The code below will somewhat show what I'm trying to do. I need the top level type to be an array, and the items of the array to contain allOf what inside the `base.json` file, and oneOf the specific implementation types.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "description": "Some description.",
  "items": {
    "allOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "./base.json"
      }
    ],
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "$ref": "./types/football.json"
      },
      {
        "$ref":"./types/basketball.json"
      },
      {
        "$ref":"./types/baseball.json"
      },
      {
        "$ref":"./types/hockey.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of why this isn't working for you and what you want it to do that it isn't?

Comment: So I guess my main question here is: is this valid json-schema?  I'm using a tool called `jstransform` to convert the json-schema into go models. If it isn't valid json-schema, then how can I change it so that it is? If the schema is valid, then my issue might actually be from the `jstranform` as opposed to the json-schema.

Comment: Sure that's a valid schema, but I can't say whether those references are, or if your generation implementation supports references.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need a javascript parser for that? I think JSON itself could not import other files, or maybe request that json file, then the other ones, one-by-one.

Comment: This is JSON Schema, which handles references.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).